# Cannot get enum value from a class

Tags: java, reflection

Working with a REST api, I have the following setup:

```
public enum Ready {
    YES,
    NO;
}

public class Top {
     public Ready readyField;
}
```

And several of these:

```
public class Bottom extends Top {
    ... some fields
}
```

Now, I'm doing a filter on the classes that extend the Top class. So I'm using Reflection to try and get the field value and if it fails the filter, the instance doesn't get returned.

One such filter could be on the "readyField". So let's say my url looks like this: "http.../?isReady=no".

My code looks like this:

```
Field field = Bottom.class.getField("readyField");
Class<?> type = field.getType();
if (type.isEnum()) {
    Object object = field.get(Bottom.class);
    if (!object.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
        resultList.remove(instance);
        continue;
    }
}
```

The value field is the "no" string from the URL.

This throws an execption:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set Ready field
>   Top.readyField to java.lang.Class

And I'm stumped. Everything I could find on Google relates to getting enum values from the enum class itself. Nothing about trying to compare the string value of an assigned enum field in a class using that enum.

I've already got the object instances I need. What I need is to get the value of the enum in the class and compare that to the given string.

EDIT:

The solution, it appears, is not using Bottom.class, but an actual instance of said class for the get() function.

This is what the accepted answer says, but the wording was a bit strange to me.

Comment: For automatism `enum Ready { yes, no };`. Otherwise maybe  `Enum.valueOf(type, string.toUpperCase())` is something for you. I am not entirely sure what you want in concreto.

Comment: @JoopEggen What I want is to see if the string given to me in the URL corresponds with the enum value set to the object instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to [`Field#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-) needs to be an instance where the field appears, not the `Class` object of such an instance.

> Returns the value of the field represented by this `Field`, on the specified object.

So you'd need something like

```
Bottom bottom = ...;
...
Object object = field.get(bottom);
```

Similarly, [`Field#set(Object, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) expects the first argument to be an instance on which to set the field value.

> Sets the field represented by this `Field` object on the specified
>   object argument to the specified new value.

Comment: That's all in the code already. It's right there. Everything you said about getting the field is already in the example I gave.

Comment: @KdgDev You're doing `field.get(Bottom.class)` which is very different from `field.get(someBottomInstance)`.

Comment: I don't understand why you are even mentioning the set method. It is not present in my code and I'm not talking about it.

Comment: @KdgDev I'll remove that if you want. Presumably, if you are using `get`, you may be using `set` later. It emphasizes that the argument should be an instance of the type containing the field rather than the type itself.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm coming over a bit harsh. This problem is the weirdest thing I've seen in a long time, apart from VerifyErrors, and not being able to solve it is frustrating.

Comment: @KdgDev Are you having new errors? Edit your question with the updated details. We'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the request parameter from the URL to a Bottom object:

```
String requestParam = reqest.getRequestParameter("isReady"); // "no"
requestParam = requestParam.toUpperCase(); // "NO"

// Case typed
Bottom bottom = new Bottom();
bottom.isReady = Ready.valueOf(requestParam);

// Case via reflection:
Object struct = new Bottom();
Field field = Bottom.class.getField("readyField");
Class<?> type = field.getType();
if (type.isEnum()) {
    Object value = Enum.valueOf(requestParam);
    field.set(struct, value);
}
```